# Integrate integrals where $x$ is on the bound

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to compute $\int^1_0 \int^x_0 (x-t)f(t)\,dt\,dx$? I tried to use foundamental theorem of calculus with $\int^x_0 f(t)\,dt=F(x)-F(0)$ but seems don't work when I need to integrate again.

In my book there is a one-line conclusion. If
$$\frac{du}{dx}=\int^x_0f(t)\,dt$$
then
$$u=\int^x_0(x-t) f(t)\,dt+C$$

I've no idea how this is computed either. I just used Leibniz rule and found that it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: By changing order of integration. $\int^1_0 \int^x_0 (x-t)f(t)\,dt\,dx=\int^1_0 \int^1_t (x-t)f(t)dxdt$.

Answer (score 2):

It's best you draw your integration domain in $x,t$ space. It's a triangle. Put $x$ on the horizontal axis and $t$ ond the vertical, you are integrating across the lower triangle below the diagonal. If you exchange the limits of integration, you get (reading limits from the image, for each chosen $t$ in the outer integral, check what $x$ should be used):

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \ldots dt\,dx=\int_0^1\int_t^1 \ldots dx\,dt$$
You can now integrate the inner integral without knowing anything about $f$ and you get a single integral.